# MoviePy swaps the height and width of the video

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, clip, moviepy

I am trying to work with MoviePy, but every time I work with a video whose height is greater than its width, MoviePy swaps the height and width of the video, as you can see in the picture. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWmIq.png)
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this please?

```
def compress_video(old_video_filename, new_video_filename):
    video = VideoFileClip(str(UPLOAD_FOLDER) + str(old_video_filename))
    video.write_videofile(str(UPLOAD_FOLDER) + str(new_video_filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I am a little late for the answer, but this is for anyone else facing the same issue.
For some reason moviepy was automatically swapping the height and width as mentioned in the question, so the workaround I used was to use FFMPEG directly. FFMPEG preserved the original height and width. Sample code for the above issue would be:

```py
import os
import subprocess 
def compress_video(old_video_filename, new_video_filename):
    command = f"ffmpeg -i {old_video_filename} -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 {new_video_filename}"
    #crf value compresses the video, higher values means more compression and lower quality
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0:
        print(f"Error occurred: {stderr}")
        print(old_video_filename)
    else:
        "Video compression successful"

source_dir = '/Path/to/source'
for file_name in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if file_name.endswith('.mp4'):
        compress_video(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), os.path.join(source_dir, file_name.replace('.mp4', '_compressed.mp4')))
```

This function will compress all the videos in a particular folder (assuming the videos are .mp4 videos). The ffmpeg command can also be executed using `subprocess.run()`.